# How to Run Item Fulfillment Script

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

I have User Event script according to Item Fulfillment record.

I want to test but where I could test it?
How could I change its record?

Any help would appreciate.

Comment: please add some more details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could run it fulfilling orders as follows.

Overview/Sales/Fulfill Orders/ 
Click fulfill you want.
Submitting it that script could be executed.

Hope this could help you

Comment: You can also view existing sales order then there will be a button "Fulfill". Just click it.